# Can't ping one system through VPN, but I can ping the rest of the network

Tags: vpn, ping

Working from home I connect through a VPN to the VPN server of the office configured on top of ClearOS.

From home I can ping all the office except one system. A Compact Rio from National Instruments.

If I connect to my office workstation with remote desktop, then locally I can ping all the office, including the CompactRio. So it's online and responding.

What can make the CRio to respond to ping requests only from local mates and ignore my home computer through the VPN? What's the difference if connecting through VPN is the same as being locally?

EDIT: (ampliation)

The office network is a single and basic LAN with 192.168.100.XXX IPs. I can ping the computer at 192.168.100.33 but not the CRio at 192.168.100.32 (throgh VPN). Both are in the same range of IPs so I don't know what can be different.

Please ask for further needed information if this isn't enought.

Thanks for your time,

H25E

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of ACL or firewall may be running on the VPN that is preventing you from accessing certain addresses or address ranges.

Comment: There isn't. Is a very simple network of a very little company. All IP's are from the same range and type.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily rule out an ACL running on the VPN.  If the company is small enough, you could ask the VPN maintainer.  Another possible explanation, since you said all IPs are in the same range, is that the VPN is performing NAT/PAT, putting your remote device in a different IP range, and the device is configured to only accept LAN connections.  You can check this by checking if the IP you're assigned on the VPN is part of the same subnet as the device you're trying to connect to.

Comment: The VPN configurator/mantainer it's me :D. I'm still learning about all this, so my knowledge isn't very high. If I run ipconfig in the home PC I see address:10.8.0.6, mask:255.255.255.252. Our local IPs in the office are 192.168.100.x with 255.255.255.0 mask. Is it here the problem? But I can ping W10 computers at 192.168.100.26 and 192.168.100.33, and as far as I know I should be in the same IP range to comunicate with them and I do communicate. But in the other hand I can't access the CRio at 192.168.100.32...

Comment: Please update the question with additional information about the VPN and its configuration, as well as relevant network topology.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I can VNC to my work PC through VPN, I can ping my work PC from another machine in the office (via SSH), but I cannot ping my work PC from my home PC.